# Is there anything like dynamic closure is out there in groovy? if yes then what is the difference between dynamic closure and normal closure

Tags: grails, groovy

What exactly the dynamic closure is? and what is the difference between a normal closure and dynamic closure?
Can someone provide some code example of the dynamic closure along with some brief description?

Comment: Where did you read about dynamic closures?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488378/groovy-dsl-creating-dynamic-closures-from-strings

Comment: Saw this and was wondering if anything like this is out there, that's why I asked, and if I had got something somewhere about this then why would I asked over here.

Comment: http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Playing-with-dynamic-closure-td3971250.html,
he also talked about dynamic in the closure just wanted to clear the topic

Comment: I saw it some other places too..if still not satisfied then I can try to get those links again..
:)

Comment: I think they are just talking about trying to create closures dynamically (from Strings), not "dynamic closures". There's no such thing as "dynamic closures" AFAIK

Comment: ok thanks tim_yates, I thought the same but got it some places so wanted to clear it out.
thanks a lot